# Why does mapi32.dll on Windows Server 2022 prevent calling CoInitializeSecurity within the same application?

Tags: c++, winapi, outlook, mapi, windows-server-2022

I'm working on a project that uses mapi32.dll to access Microsoft Exchange Server from a Windows Server 2022 machine. I noticed that whenever CoInitializeSecurity is called within the same application after calling MAPIInitialize, it fails with the error "RPC_E_TOO_LATE: The call to CoInitializeSecurity has already been made and cannot be called again within the same application."

This isn't a new project. It has been in production for years, but after a customer upgraded to Windows Server 2022 they reported this issue and the above is what I found after investigating it.

After doing some research, I found that mapi32.dll in Windows Server 2022 seems to call CoInitializeSecurity during initialization. I swapped this DLL with one from Windows Server 2019 and everything work as expected. CoInitializeSecurity was able to be called afterwards with no failure.

One solution is to move the call to CoInitializeSecurity to just before calling MAPIInitialize, but my concern is that the security needed by MAPI would be different, or somehow cause problems with it.

Does anyone know why mapi32.dll in Windows Server 2022 prevents calling CoInitializeSecurity within the same application? Is there a way to work around this issue? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `mapi32.dll` may not be calling `CoInitializeSecurity` directly - _"... If a process does not call CoInitializeSecurity, COM calls it automatically the first time an interface is marshaled or unmarshaled, registering the system default security. No default security packages are registered until then...."_ [CoInitializeSecurity - Remarks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/combaseapi/nf-combaseapi-coinitializesecurity#remarks).  There may be code change in `mapi32.dll` causing the automatic call to happen.

Comment: Where did you get the MAPI subsystem to install on the server? Did you install Outlook?

Comment: Wild guess, but that may be due to DCOM hardening which is a fairly recent update in the Windows ecosystem: https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/windows-it-pro-blog/dcom-authentication-hardening-what-you-need-to-know/ba-p/3657154 As a COM/RPC client, it may be possible that MAPI now calls CoInitializeSecurity to explicitly use RPC_C_AUTHN_LEVEL_PKT_INTEGRITY auth level. If your code lives in the same process, you can (should) use COM security at interface level: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/com/setting-security-at-the-interface-proxy-level

Comment: @EugeneAstafiev Yes Outlook was installed.

Comment: Is there any difference in Outlook versions installed on both machines?

Comment: @SimonMourier Thanks for that. That is most likely the reason I would think. A bit frustrating though because if they call it first my software is unable to set the security level to something different.

Comment: @EugeneAstafiev Yes. The Outlook on Window's Server 2022 is much newer as expected and the mapi32.dll is newer also. Presumably they made a change to increase the DCOM security by setting it inside the new DLL.

Comment: Looks so, or may be some bugs were fixed to close the backdoor. Can you specify the exact Outlook versions you have installed?

Comment: @EugeneAstafiev After closer inspection it seems the 2019 machine I copied the working mapi32.dll from didn't have outlook installed. Product version: 10.0.17763.3113 On the non-working version (2022) the dll Product version: 10.0.20348.380. Outlook on the 2022 machine: 16.0.16327.20248

Comment: Have you checked the product history? Are there any mentions for such cases?

Comment: @EugeneAstafiev I'm unsure where to find that. I searched for it, but I didn't turn up anything.

Comment: See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/officeupdates/update-history-microsoft365-apps-by-date